# Cuts off the Zero while formatting through Moment.js

Tags: momentjs

import moment from 'moment';

```
var incidentdate = 01/08/2022;
moment.locale('en-nz');
var incidentDateNZFormat = moment(incidentdate,"DD-MM-YYYY").format('LL');
```

After the format  1 August 2022 is retrieved without Zero before 1 due to which my test is failing for example

```
+ expected - actual

  -11:00 AM, 08 August 2022
  +11:00 AM, 8 August 2022
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: LL is the root cause mehak. @mehak

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/ read this format doc

Comment: If you will not able to find any solution from the doc then I will help.